# Enable scrolling on disabled listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, scrollbar, disabled-control

when i disable a `listview` in vb.net by setting `Enabled=False`, the scrolling is disabled too so i can't see all the items in the `list`. Is there a way to disable user interaction on the `list` but preserve the `scrolling` so that the user can't select any item but can `drag the scrollbars`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do this? You will end up with a list view that looks like it should function normally, but users will not be able to select any items.

This could potentially be very confusing.

If this is really what you want (and I advise against it), you could add a handler to the `ItemSelectionChanged` event that deselects whichever item has just been selected.

Comment: This works thanks. Anyway i don't understand why this seems so strange to you, i think that a disabled control should prevent user interactions but you should be able to see all the data that it contains, since it doesn't exist a "readonly" property for listviews

Comment: Because some people might become confused by two controls that looked identical but behaved differently.